# MFMessageViewController turns to white screen when presented

Tags: ios, swift

I have presented MFMessageViewController with following code.

```
extension TransactionResultViewController {
  func showMessageComposeController() {
    if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
        let messageComposeVc = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        messageComposeVc.body = viewModel.offlinePayload
        messageComposeVc.recipients = ["37245"]
        messageComposeVc.messageComposeDelegate = self
        self.present(messageComposeVc, animated: true, completion: nil)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    }
  }
}
```

and dismissed with following code.

```
func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Sometimes the MFMessageviewcontroller is not presented and sometimes it shows blank white/black screen. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Are you tried without `extension`, directly inside of the `class`?

Comment: no.. does it matter ?

Comment: I don't understand, your current implementation is automatically presented? There is no any triggers

Comment: no no ,its trigerred by IBAction

Comment: Put your code to `@IBAction`

Comment: tried it doesnt work

Comment: Try something like without an initial `body` and `recipients` while presenting.

Comment: Check this line of code using `print-statement`: `print(viewModel.offlinePayload)`. I think it's too large file to load initially.

Comment: its just a string with count = 64